# How to not have partition name when creating partitions via Hive

Tags: hive, orc

We have a table (table1) which is partitioned on year, month and day. 
I created an orc table similar to table1 with similar partitions but of type ORC. I am trying to insert
date into partitions using the following statement but i am getting data dumped in folders with partition names.
How can i make sure where the folders don't have partition names in them?

```
create external table table1_orc(
col1 string,
col2 string,
col3 int
PARTITIONED BY ( 
`year` string,
`month` string,
`day` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/base_path_orc/';

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
insert overwrite table table1_orc partition(year,month,day) select * from table1 where year = '2015' and month = '10' and day = '01';
```

Path to table1 in hdfs - /base_path/2015/10/01/data.csv

Path to orc table in hdfs (current output) -/base_path_orc/year=2015/month=10/day=01/000000_0

Desired output - /base_path_orc/2015/10/01/000000_0

Comment: Why do you need specifically that kind of output? It's a way to store partition data in hive.

Comment: To keep the file structure same in hdfs as raw files. Raw files just have Y/M/d and not Year=Y/Month=M etc